# convert to N.A if count less than 5

Tags: awk, count

I have a space-delimited large file with thousands of rows and columns. I would like to convert value to N.A if its count is less than 5 in a row.

Input:

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 450 461 559 765 850
SNP1    0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2
SNP2    2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0
SNP3    -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0   0   0   0   0
SNP4    0   0   0   -1  -1  2   2   2   2   2
SNP5    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
```

Output:

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 450 461 559 765 850
SNP1    0   0   0   0   0   0   N.A N.A N.A N.A
SNP2    2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0
SNP3    N.A N.A N.A N.A 0   0   0   0   0   0
SNP4    N.A N.A N.A N.A N.A 2   2   2   2   2
SNP5    1   1   1   1   1   1   N.A N.A N.A N.A
```

I am using these commands to achieve desired output:

Calculate count for zero:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/0/,"") "\t" NR}' input_ > output_1
```

Extracting count column:

```
awk '{print $1}' output_1 > output_1_col_1
```

Merging count with original file:

```
paste -d " " output_1_col_1 original_file > output_2
```

Convert value into N.A where count is less than 5:

```
awk '$1 < 6{gsub("0","N.A")}1' output_2 > Final_output
```

Similarly I am repeating these steps to calculate count for 1, 2 and -1.

Is there any better and quicker way to get desired output?

Answer (score 3):

With a single pass through the file: still need to iterate over the fields twice.

```
awk '
    FNR > 1 {
        delete count
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) count[$i]++
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if (count[$i] < 5) $i = "N.A"
    }
    1
' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(++count==1){
    print
  }
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    a[FNR,$i]++
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    $i=a[FNR,$i]<5?"N.A":$i
  }
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 450 461 559 765 850
SNP1 0 0 0 0 0 0 N.A N.A N.A N.A
SNP2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
SNP3 N.A N.A N.A N.A 0 0 0 0 0 0
SNP4 N.A N.A N.A N.A N.A 2 2 2 2 2
SNP5 1 1 1 1 1 1 N.A N.A N.A N.A
```

Comment: @WaqasKhokhar, sure cool, as you was asking previously. To best answer you could reward it as correct answer(after sometime when you see some answers) and to others up-vote you could give since they tried to help you too, happy learning.

Comment: I will surely follow your advice :-)